# aggration and self join

Tags: join, aggregation

hi I am working on this query, wondering whether there is a good way to achieve. TableA as

```
zone_no   price     produceDate
54         12.33     20161201
58         7.88      20161224
64         28.27     20160812
67         20.45      20160405
87         14.08      20161102
92         1.69       20160101
101        12.57      20140501
141        22.21      20150601
157        14.28      20160417

select max(price) from tableA where zone_no between 54 and 145

select max(price) from tableA where Zone_no between 92 and 141

outcome: 
price(Zone 54-145)  price(zone 92-141)
28.27                   22.57
```

how to achieve this without CTE? thanks

Comment: can u makes use of an union, or u want the values next to eachother

Comment: i want them each to other if it is ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution

```
select sum(een), sum(twee) from (

select max(price) as een, 0 as twee from tableA where zone_no between 54 and 145
union
select 0, max(price) from tableA where Zone_no between 92 and 141

)
```